# Can I play my Minecraft Classic Levels in Minecraft Beta?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Before I bought Minecraft Beta I made some huge structures in Minecraft Classic. Can I import these levels into Minecraft Beta somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [MCEdit](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/13807-mcedit-minecraft-world-editor-compatible-with-mc-beta-173) to import the .mine file (used by classic) into an existing beta world. I don't know how this will affect classic blocks that are not used by the beta version though.

[Source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/606524-minecraft/answers?qid=259307)

Comment: I believe block IDs which Beta doesn't recognize will vanish into thin air, a.k.a. block ID 0 (this got added around the time of the Locked Chest joke's removal); I don't know whether MCEdit will translate wool colors, for example, into the new format.